# AttributeError: module 'dotenv' has no attribute 'find_dotenv'

Tags: flask

Following this tutorial: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Based on the tutorial (first chapter), created this diagram:

[image]

Using VS Code (provided as part of CS50 courses on Edx).

After running this command on the terminal:

```
pip install Flask
```

Created microblog directory. I am approaching this without virtual environment.

Under microblog directory, app directory with 2 files:

1. **init**.py

   from flask import Flask
   app = Flask(**name**)
   from app import routes
2. routes.py

   from app import app
   @app.route('/')
   @app.route('/index')
   def index():
   return "Hello World!"

Created microblog.py within microblog directory:

```
from app import app
```

Next, on the terminal, ran this command while within microblog directory:

```
export FLASK_APP=microblog.py
```

Finally, this command on terminal while on microblog directory:

```
flask run
```

This is the output on the terminal:

```
    microblog/ $ flask run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cs50/lib/flask", line 19, in 
<module>
    sys.exit(flask.cli.main())
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-
```

packages/flask/cli.py",
line 1107, in main
cli.main()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-
packages/click/core.py",
line 1077, in main
with self.make_context(prog_name,
args, **extra) as ctx:

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
microblog/ $   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-
packages/flask/cli.py", line 662, in
make_context
load_dotenv()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-
packages/flask/cli.py",
line 739, in load_dotenv
path = dotenv.find_dotenv(name,
usecwd=True)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'dotenv' has no
attribute 'find_dotenv'

Help appreciated where I am going wrong.